# Javascript functions are not working in Firefox new version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, firefox

I have the following below function which disables to enter numbers or special characters in the text box. This function are working fine in IE and Chrome, but in the firefox these are not working and am able to enter the numbers and characters. Can anyone please suggest how this can be resolved in firefox? My FF version is 57.0.4

```
$("#firstName").keypress(function(event) {
        var character = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        return isValid(character);     
    });


        function isValid(str) {
            return !/[~`!@#$%\^&*()+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
        }

         $( document ).ready(function() {
             $( "#firstName" ).keypress(function(e) {
                 var key = e.keyCode;
                 if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                 }
             });
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in Firefox's console?

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket and parenthesis.

Comment: I am not getting anything on the console, the bracket is there in the actual code i just put the small snippet here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyCode` is deprecated. jQuery normalizes this property for cross browser usage in the [`event.which`](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property.

```js
$("#firstName").keypress(function(event) {
  var character = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  return isValid(character);
});


function isValid(str) {
  return !/[~`!@#$%\^&*()+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
}

$("#firstName").keypress(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id=firstName />
```

Comment: Note that the event object being examined in this code is the jQuery-wrapped version.

Comment: Looks like replacing keyCode with charCode worked in firefox. Is charCode compatible in all browsers? Is this also getting deprecated too?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I think jQuery always normalizes to the property "which" for the character code.

Comment: @Pointy - Yeah i just realizedd that as soon as I posted that other comment. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! That really helped to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To disables to enter numbers or special characters you can use

```
/[~`!#@$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,_./{}\(\)\|\\":<>\d+$?]/g
```

[You can try this regex Here](https://regexr.com/3jj99) And instead of using `keypress()` you can use `.on('input')` .. The next code works for me in chrome , firefox and IE

```js
$("#firstName").on( 'input' ,function(event) {
  var ThisVal = $(this).val();
  if(isValid(ThisVal) == false){
   $(this).val(ThisVal.substr(0, ThisVal.length - 1));
  }
});


function isValid(str) {
  return !/[~`!#@$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,_./{}\(\)\|\\":<>\d+$?]/g.test(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id=firstName />
```

> **Note**: I don't care here to use `e.which` or `e.keyCode` because no need to in this case .. Also this regex will disable `_` and `.` and `-` if you need any of those you can remove it